# Frontend / backend synchronization during deployment

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, bitbucket, jira, bitbucket-pipelines

Currently, I have two separate Bitbucket repositories for Frontend / backend respectively. Each repo has its own Bitbucket Pipelines configuration which works independently from each other. Sometimes, we run into a situation when a frontend is broken because there are no corresponding backend changes deployed or vice versa - backend deployed something not yet supported by frontend.

I have an idea on how to solve it - triggering backend deployment from frontend merging related backed pull requests with the help of merge checks to prevent merges  if backend is not ready yet.

Probably, there are other strategies exist or I might try some tool out to achieve my goal.

Please advise on this topic